# ant convert path separator

Tags: ant, path

Within an ant file, I am trying to convert windows style path separators to unix style.  I have the following:

```
<path id="basedir.path">
    <!-- ${basedir} is a project attribute. -->
    <pathelement path="${basedir}" />
</path>
<pathconvert property="adjusted_basedir" refid="basedir.path">
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="*" to="*" handledirsep="yes"/>
    </mapper>
</pathconvert>
<echo level="verbose" message="Basedir: ${basedir}" /> 
<echo level="verbose" message="Adj Basedir: ${adjusted_basedir}" />
```

but the output of `adjusted_basedir` is the same as `basedir`. I have tried using

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="\\" to="/" />
```

but then the output of `adjusted_basedir` is simply "/".  How do I convert path separators from windows to unix style?  I want to avoid using add-ons to ant for this (so ant-contrib is out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `filtermapper`:

```
<pathconvert property="adjusted_basedir" refid="basedir.path">
    <filtermapper>
        <replacestring from="\" to="/" />
    </filtermapper>
</pathconvert>
```

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html.

There is also an attribute to do this in the `pathconvert` task:

```
<pathconvert property="adjusted_basedir" refid="basedir.path" dirsep="/" />
```

Comment: I found the `filtermapper` shortly after posting.  I completely missed the `dirsep` attribute, that worked a treat!

Comment: This is an excellent choice when one needs to sanctify the separators!